# Laravel query on same table for associated users

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model

I am using Laravel 5.2 and trying to build a query to create a table of the top 5 users who have referred other users in the past 30 days.

Currently the user table has a column 'referral' which contains the ID of the user who referred them. I'll include my current query below to give you an idea. But basically I would like to return a list of 5 users who have the most referrals, ordered by most to least, so I can create my leaderboard table.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
$top5_referrers = User::join('users_roles_link', 'users_roles_link.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
                                ->where('users_roles_link.role_id',12)
                                ->whereDate('user.created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()->subDay(30)->toDateString())
                                ->select(
                                    DB::raw('
                                        user.id, user.username
                                        (SELECT COUNT(u.id) FROM user u WHERE u.referral = user.id AND u.referral IS NOT NULL AND u.created_at >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AS total_signups
                                    '))
                                ->groupBy('user.id')
                                ->orderBy('total_signups', 'desc')
                                ->take(5)
                                ->get();
```

Now I know I'm going wrong by already having a where on users with role_id of 12 (which are mod's for those wondering, the only ones I'm interested in for this list of referrers!), I'm limiting the results to these mods, when really I need to bring back a list of only mods, but base that list on the users.

There are 14,000+ users of this system, so I need to do this as light on the db server as is possible. Can anyone offer any advice? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so incase anyone finds this in future.

I was over thinking the query. I just needed to grab all users with role '12' in the first where then remove the whereDate as I needed ALL users with role 12, not just the new starters.

Then in the DB::raw I was able to select the users with a referral matching the current user referenced.

Silly me.